# Pass bash array to stdin

Tags: bash, stdin

I currently have a bash script like this, which successfully calls the program `prog`:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=hello
var2=world
prog <<EOF
$var1
$var2
EOF
```

Instead of `var1` and `var2`, how would I pass each element within an array (of unknown length, since I am using $@) to `prog` in the same manner?

Comment: do you mean `vars=('hello' 'world'); prog ${vars[@]}`?

Comment: @Uroc327 That would pass each element as a separate positional parameter, instead of one element per line on standard input.

Comment: Would that work if `prog` asks first for a line of input from stdin, waits a bit, then asks for a second, etc.?

Comment: No; positional arguments are completely separate from standard input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you would want something like

```
for line in "$@"; do
    echo "$line"
done | prog
```

It's not a here document, but it has the same effect. Here documents and arrays were developed for two different use cases.

Even more strictly speaking, `$@` is not an array, although it tries very hard to behave like one. :)

Comment: Thanks! I would never have thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

You could loop over each element of the array and echo each value into the program:

```
vars=('foo' 'foo bar' 'bar')
for var in "${vars[@]}"; do echo $var; done | prog
```

**FAIRNESS UPDATE**: @chepner beat me to this answer by a few seconds :)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you cannot pass *variables*, but you can pass *arguments*, so here's a fix:

```
prog $VAR1 $VAR2 <<EOF
```

And inside `prog` you could use:

```
ARR=($@)
```

to save all the positional parameters to the variable `ARR`.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of expanding an array into a set of lines, one per element, in a here doc.

Comment: I don't see this requirement anywhere

Comment: He wants to use an array in place of individual variables, which are currently used one per line in a here document.